# Downloading files from filesystem using spring rest controller and angular

Tags: java, angular, spring

In a project I want to view files and folders under a root folder and be able to download these files or navigate in folders.

For txt, json, log extensions the files are successfully downloaded but for other types like xlsx I get strange errors like the one below

```
sendMessage:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'P', "PK " is not a valid JSON...
```

It is trying to parse a json file.

I am using a @RepositoryRestController with the Java code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/file/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void downloadFile(@RequestParam String path, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws Exception {

    String filename = path.contains("\\") ? path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) : path;
    String fullPath = filesPath + path;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
        "attachment; filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") + "\"");

    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(fullPath);
    File file = fileSystemResource.getFile();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
  }
```

And the angular code:

```
getFile(file: FileElement) {
    this.http
      .get<HttpResponse<any>>("rest/user/file/download", {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().append(
          "Content-Type",
          this.getMimeType(file.name)
        ),
        observe: "response",
        params: { path: file.path },
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          this.donwloadingFile(res, "success");
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(error);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  getMimeType(filename: string) {
    var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
    var ext = re.exec(filename)[1];
    switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
      case "zip":
        return "application/zip";
      case "json":
        return "application/json";
      case "txt":
        return "text";
      case "log":
        return "text";
      case "csv":
        return "text/csv";
      case "xlsx":
        return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
      case "xls":
        return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    }
  }

  donwloadingFile(res: HttpResponse<any>, SuccessMsg: string) {
    console.log("download res: ", res);
    if (res === null || res === undefined || typeof res == undefined) return false;
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
      var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
      var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
      if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
        filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
      }
    }
    var type = res.headers.get('Content-Type');
    var blob = new Blob([res.body], { type: type });

    let nav: any = window.navigator;
    if (nav && nav.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      nav.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
    } else {
      var file = new File([blob], filename, { type: type, lastModified: Date.now() });
      var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
      fileLink.href = objectUrl;
      fileLink.download = filename;
      fileLink.target = "_self";
      fileLink.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));

      setTimeout(function () {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        fileLink.remove();
      }, 0);
    }

    this.comServ.sendMessage(SuccessMsg, 'S');
    return true;
  }
```

Any ideas how to download any type of file in browser?